# How to reuse a stream (fs.ReadStream) in typescript

Tags: typescript

I would like to be able to take an fs.ReadStream and upload it with retries - but the stream is not useable after first try.

```
const buf = fs.createReadStream(filePath)
for (let i = 0; i < times; i++) {
   try {
       await upload(buf)
   }catch(e){
       console.log(e)
   }
}
```

Comment: Why? That's not how streams work... What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I’m creating a library for users to upload stream to my service I want to do myself a retry mechanism

Answer (score 0):

Ended up finding this solution best for me: write strean into array (using stream-array library) and stream the array (using stream-to-array). This way I can use the array as many times as I want for different usages without the concern of chaining pipes would fail if one fails.